# get a column click in dataTables plugin instead of row

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have the following code that works great for row click, but I want the first and last column to be clickable and I want to be able to tell which column was clicked. I have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable();
    var fa = 0;
    $('#submit tbody td ').click(function() {
    var gCard = $('#mytable tbody').delegate("tr", "click", rowClick);


    });
    function rowClick() {
        fa = this;
        var id  = $("td:eq(1)", this).text();
        cardNumber = $.trim(id);    
        $.ajax({
            url : 'myurltopostto',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                id  :   id

            },
            success : function(data) {
                oTable.fnDraw(); //wanted to update here
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

the code here is the row click

```
var gCard = $('#mytable tbody').delegate("tr", "click", rowClick);
```

what can I do for a cell click and get info.

using jquery plugin dataTables
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do it `$('#submit tbody td ').click(function() ...` you bind click event to the `td`.
So, to get the first and last column click use the following:

```
$('td:first, td:last', '#submit tbody tr').on('click', function() {
    // do what you want
});
```

[**demo1**](http://jsfiddle.net/hua8Z/)

**updated 1**:
Get last two columns:

```
jQuery('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    jQuery('td', this).slice(-2).on('click', function() {
        // do what you want
    });
});
```

[**demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/hua8Z/2/)

**update 2**: Get each column data on click last two columns

```
jQuery('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    jQuery('td', this).slice(-2).on('click', function() {
        // do what you want
        var $columns = jQuery(this).siblings('td').andSelf();
        jQuery.each($columns, function(i, item) {
            alert(jQuery(item).html());
        });
    });
});
```

[**demo3**](http://jsfiddle.net/hua8Z/4/)

Comment: Can you clarify your question please ?

Comment: instead of first and last column, I just want the click on last two columns

Comment: this works but only one issue? how would I get the values of the other cells??? it just gives me the values of the last two cells. I want to be able to only click last to cells but I need value of all the cells. Just not being able to click them.

Comment: somethng like this http://jsfiddle.net/hua8Z/3/ but it doesnt work...trying to get the value of first cell

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13187/discussion-between-ricardo-lohmann-and-autolycus)

Answer (score 2):

Just specify a column number instead of first, last, etc. The example below shows column 12. zero is first. It's easier that way.

```
td:eq(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#tableID').DataTable();

    $('#tableID').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
    } );
} );
```

for more refer this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html)